# Primefaces cant fill inputText in dialog after click contextmenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces Datatable-ContextMenu and Dialog to update a row (When after click to contextmenu it opens a dialog which contains will update object's fields in `<p:inputext />`).

I have tried dynamic true, initilazing object on constructor because when page is rendered selectedObject will be null in dialog  and when I tried to use it gives null pointer exception so that i need other advices.

**Here is ContextMenu:**

```
<p:contextMenu for="functions" id="functionContextMenu">  
<p:menuitem value="Guncelle" icon="ui-icon-" update="updateDialog" oncomplete="updateDialog.show()"/>
```

**And my dialog is here:**

```
<p:dialog header="Guncelle" widgetVar="updateDialog" resizable="false"
width="200" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" id="updateDialog" dynamic="true">  
    <h:panelGroup id="display">  
        <h:outputText value="#{functionControllerBean.selectedFunction.functionName}" />
        <h:inputText id="firstName" value="{functionControllerBean.tempSelectedFunction1.functionName}" />  
    </h:panelGroup>  
</p:dialog>
```

If I dont use `<p:inputText />` its ok and show what i put `<h:outputText />` but when i put p:inputext inside of dialog;it doesnt show output text value and shows `<p:inputText />` empty even its not.

I had used `beanname.objectname.field` before inside of `<p:inputText />` or `<h:inputText />` but there was no problem but now it's not working.

**And here is my ManagedBean :**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FunctionControllerBean implements Serializable {
    private EfaFunctions willAddFunction;
    private EfaFunctions selectedFunction = new EfaFunctions();
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE** Here is page

```
<h:form id="form">   
        <p:contextMenu for="functions" id="functionContextMenu">  
            <p:menuitem value="Guncelle" icon="ui-icon-" update="updateDialog"  oncomplete="updateDialog.show()"/>                  
            <p:menuitem value="Sil" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{functionControllerBean.deleteFunction}"/>  
        </p:contextMenu>  
        <p:dataTable resizableColumns="true" id="functions" var="function" value="#{functionControllerBean.functions}" rowKey="#{function.functionId}"  
                     selection="#{functionControllerBean.selectedFunction}" selectionMode="single">  

            <p:column headerText="Id">  
                #{function.functionId}  
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Key ">  
                #{function.functionKey}  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Isim" >  
                #{function.functionName}  
            </p:column>          
            <p:column headerText="Tip" >  
                #{function.functionType}  
            </p:column>   
            <p:column headerText="Url" >  
                #{function.uri}  
            </p:column>    
            <p:column headerText="Olusturulma Tarihi" >  
                #{function.creationDate}  
            </p:column>          
            <p:column headerText="Guncelleme Tarihi" >  
                #{function.lastUpdateDate}  
            </p:column>          
            <p:column headerText="Olusturan Kisi" >  
                #{function.createdBy}  
            </p:column>          
            <p:column headerText="Guncelleyen Kisi" >  
                #{function.createdBy}  
            </p:column>          

        </p:dataTable>   
        <p:dialog header="Islem  Sonucu" widgetVar="actionResult" resizable="false"  
                  width="200" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" id="actionResult"
                  visible="#{functionControllerBean.actionResult!=null}"> 
            <h:outputText value="#{functionControllerBean.actionResult}"/>
        </p:dialog>

        <p:dialog header="Guncelle" widgetVar="updateDialog" resizable="false"
                  width="200" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" id="updateDialog" >  
            <h:panelGroup id="display">  
                <h:outputText value="#{functionControllerBean.selectedFunction.functionName}" />
                <p:inputText value="#{functionControllerBean.selectedFunction.functionName}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>  
        </p:dialog>  

    </h:form>
```

Comment: Try puting a form inside your dialog and see if it helps.

Comment: @Jedrus Thanks for  comment but its already in a form